# Print a radio type input with a value from a array using a for loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, printing

This is **$data**:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'user_username' => string 'kevin' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'user_username' => string 'afid' (length=4)
```

Here is my loop:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) { 
            # code...
            print "<input name=\"option\" type=\"radio\">";
        }
```

How I can takes this values from the array "kevin" and "afid" as the input value?

I want to print this out:

```
<input name="option" type="radio" value="kevin">
<input name="option" type="radio" value="afid">
```

Comment: `$data[$i]['user_username']` maybe?  I would use a `foreach`.

Comment: I try that... But the problem is with the double quotes and quotes, I can't make it work...

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($data as $line){
   echo '<input name="option" value="' . $line['user_username']. '" type="radio">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your loop to the following:

```
$data = ("kevin", "afid");

foreach($data as $name){

    print '<input name="option" type="radio" value="$name">';
}
```